# Как скачать файл из ресурсов в Visual Basic?

Tags: visual-basic

В ресурсах проекта есть zip архив. Надо при нажатии на кнопку, чтобы этот файл скачался на рабочий стол. В каком направлении двигаться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если zip архив отмечен как embedded resource, то примерно так:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim targetPath = IO.Path.Combine(desktopPath, "TextFile.zip")

    ' "WindowsApplication1.TextFile1.zip" нужно заменить на настоящее имя ресурса
    ' в формате "<default namespace>.<папка>.<файл>"
    Using resourceStream = Me.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication1.TextFile1.zip")
        Using fileStream = IO.File.OpenWrite(targetPath)
            resourceStream.CopyTo(fileStream)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: `WindowsApplication1.TextFile1.zip`? o_O

Comment: @VladD лень было из студии переключаться, переименовал что было :)

Comment: Ага, но вы хотя бы намекните ТСу, что эту часть неплохо бы подправить после копипаста :)

Comment: Спасибо за первые две строчки, остальное я не понял, поэтому ошибки вылетали.
Но я вспомнил про `WriteAllBytes`
И написал
`My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(targetPath, My.Resources.SSD8, False)`